# The find methon in python not giving a correct index

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

Hi guys check out this code.

```
code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
location = work_tip.find("i")
print(location)
print (code_tip[location])
```

well I expect the find object to return the index of "i" which in this case is 11,and store in a variable location and the index is used to print the word "i" from the code-tip string, well it turns out that the find object rather returns a value of 10 instead of 11, and print outs "d" instead of "i".
Is there any error in this code cause i don't know why.
below is the output of the code

```
 code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
 location = work_tip.find("i")
 print(location)
 print (code_tip[location])
 #Output of the code.
 10  
 d
```

can anyone explain what's going on.

Comment: You aren't using the same variable, you are using `work_tip.find` but indexing into `code_tip`

Comment: Could you elaborate further

Comment: Yes, `work_tip != code_tip`, so it is not necessarily the case that `code_tip[i] == work_tip[i]`, why do you think it would be? Look, just change `print(code_tip[location])` to `print(work_tip[location])` and it will work.

Comment: Alrigth I get it now.good thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're running `find` on `work_tip`, not on `code_tip`. If you run it on the right variable you'll get the expected result:

```
>>> code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
>>> location = code_tip.find("i")
>>> print(location)
11
>>> print (code_tip[location])
i
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you mixed `code_tip` and `work_tip` at the second line. Try this:

```
 code_tip = "code a conditional decision like you would say it"
 location = code_tip.find("i")
 print(location)
 print (code_tip[location])
```

Answer (score 0):

first of always use '' and not "" for Strings and second you should look in your code_tip not work_tip, here is how you can find it

[Showing the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxTxy.png)